# Pandas groupby method to aggregate based on string contained in column

Tags: python, pandas, string

New to Pandas/Python (student).  I have what should be a simple problem but every approach I try fails.

Dataset has "country" column and "indicator" column.  Countries appear >1 time.  Indicator col tells us who is pro-vaccine ("Vac_plan" and "Vac_done") and who is not (as well as other info).  I simply want a total for each country based on the count of who is pro-vaccine for that respective country., e.g.,

```
Ethiopia  7
Nigeria   5
```

My latest failed attempts are below:

```
vaccines_by_country=df.groupby('country')['indicator'=='Vac_plan|Vac_done'].count()
```

and...

```
df.groupby(['country']).str.contains('Vac_plan|Vac_done').count()
```

TIA for your merciful help.

Comment: `df.indicator.str.contains('Vac_plan|Vac_done').groupby(df.country).sum()` ?

Comment: Ty.  Both Psidom's and richardec's produced the same results, for anyone who is interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're quite close in your second attempt; you just need to reverse the order of actions. First find the strings, *then* group:

```
df['indicator'].str.contains('Vac_plan|Vac_done').groupby(df['country']).sum()
```

Comment: Ty.  Both yours and Psidom's produced the same results, for anyone who is interested.  Thank you for the additional explanation, it helped it "click" for me.

Comment: No...I need to know more of your setup. For that, ask a new SO question providing the necessary context and information. Remember to tag it correctly :)